# "Downloaded content" or "downloaded contents" when downloading files, folders, and other elements at once

Tags: word-usage

I'm writing a message for an app. The user can select multiple files and folders to download. We're letting them navigate to the download location right after the download completes. I'm trying to find a generic word that can covers all the things that were downloaded. We cover specific cases in situations where users select a single file of a specific type.

I am wondering which one would be appropriate here:

**Go to downloaded content**

**Go to downloaded contents**

The [examples](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pl/grammar/british-grammar/content-or-contents) [I](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13556/content-or-contents) [found](https://getproofed.com/writing-tips/word-choice-content-vs-contents/) point towards "contents" as it seems that since the number of elements they've selected to download are known to the user and are specific. However it sounds odd and the "container" isn't specified in the sentence so I'm not sure it's correct. On the other hand the selection of elements seems to be the "container".

Additional context:

- We can't say *files* as we do not use this term in the app.
- We display this one only when user selects multiple elements with different types.
- In other scenarios we display the name of the element they've chosen e.g., *Go to downloaded folder*.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a good answer for a rather vague question, but as this link illustrates one possibility would be "data". Does this answer your question? [What is the noun for either a file or folder?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150806/what-is-the-noun-for-either-a-file-or-folder)

Comment: [***Content** as a **singular** noun is uncountable. It means the ideas that are contained in a piece of writing or a film or a speech.*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/content-or-contents) Looks *slightly* different to the context here, but I think adjectivally modified ***downloaded content*** is syntactically similar to the examples in the link: *This film has **adult content***, and *These hamburgers have a **high fat content***.

Comment: ...though to be honest I'm not convinced the word "content" means enough in OP's context to justify including it. Most computer contexts simply refer to a ***downloads*** directory - adding the word "content" doesn't really add anything to that.

Comment: Like @FumbleFingers suggests but doesn't quite spell out - **Go to downloads** is entirely satisfactory.  No?

Comment: Thank you for all suggestions. It is not a download folder per se. After selecting the "Go" option the user is then taken to the exact location of elements they've dowloaded and they're highlighted for them. We do not expect them to know where that is. We want to emphasize that they'll see the things they've downloaded. That's why I'm trying to find a generic word for all the types they might've selected.

Comment: **Go to downloads** is clear and used elsewhere (check your browser). If that's still rubbing you the wrong way, you could say **View content**.

Comment: Thank you @jimm101, I think that "downloads" in the browser context precisely means "the folder/location that is set as a default download location". Unfortunately in a closed app environment we don't have such place and the user navigates between their "cloud directory" and things saved "on their device". That said your other suggestion makes sense in the context and it pretty much answers the original question whether "content" or "contents" would be more appropriate here.

Comment: What about "View downloaded items"?